# convert table to div ?>

Tags: html, html-table

I need to convert this table to divs :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 aaa
</td>
<td rowspan=2>
 bbb
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
 fff
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Good for you! Now, do you have a question related to programming?

Comment: I just need 1 reputation to vote this post down! :(

Comment: @Lazarus , maybe you have another definition for programming because I've seen thousends of programming questions that need an answer why you don't go there but instead waste your time here ?

Comment: I think you guys are just too smart for such a simple question : )

Comment: @Israa Abd - You didn't ask a question, you made a statement. Even as a question, it's a lazy one. I also don't consider converting an HTML table to HTML div tags to be a programming issue unless you are writing a program to do it, in which case you should have posted your code and not your HTML. You should have further explained what you expected the code to do and how it was failing for you, we could have then helped you. This is **NOT** a pool of free resources for you to leverage to do your work for you! Now read the FAQ and try again.

Comment: too localized?  this is a valid question... although it clearly showed that the poster didn't do much homework himself...  and the close police just work 24 hours a day, it seems

Comment: How is this a valid question? Where is the question and where is it related to programming? This is a clear request for someone to do this piece of work for the OP and to provide the completed output back to them, only of use to the rep-hounds.

Comment: @Lazarus, as you see I can't give a solution for my problem and if I can I wouldn't post it and this place is not specified to just answer programming questions, but to direct us to the right way to figure out our issues , any way thank you very much .

Comment: @Israa Abd - From the FAQ, which I urged you to read, "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers … a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, software tools commonly used by programmers, matters that are unique to the programming profession … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" That seems pretty programming specific to me. If your issue is about a program then post a new question about it